# How do you create the Rule to enforce Work Item association on check-in? (TFS2010 Agile 5.0)

Tags: tfs, agile

How do you create the Rule to enforce Work Item association on check-in?  (TFS2010 Agile 5.0)

Answer (score 1):

i found it under Team policy Settings in Visual Studio.